# Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument in facebook sdk v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am getting this error when i used different user id but working on same user and app secret.

Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

```
$accessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $accessToken, app_secret); 

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => app_id,
        'app_secret' => app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
        'default_access_token' => app_id."|".app_secret
    ]);
    // FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);
    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=adaccounts{name}&appsecret_proof='.$appsecret_proof.'', $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
```

Comment: check if that user allow to take that info , privacy settings of that user. And first try if your able to get result here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Try it on this
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

If you want to provide access_token then that should be in your

It should be like below
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=<mytoken>`

First try in your developers account, you get the result with `access_token` and for getting a result you need to provide the fields only.